# How to call a JavaScript Function from href tag in html?

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

How to call a JavaScript Function from href tag in html? I have created few tabs. I want when user clicks on any tab the href along with JavaScript function should get called. How can I do it?

```
<?php if($order == 1){ ?>
<li class="cat-one"><a href= "javascript:loadProducts($categoryId)" > <?php echo $categoryName ?> </a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
<script type="javascript" >
function loadProducts($categoryId)
{
    alert("Hello World!");
    return false;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Do you have some code to show us?

Comment: You need to share some code if you want any help. If you want to display a tab and execute a JavaScript function when the user click on that tab you would generally solve this without server-side code, i.e. without PHP.

Comment: You have to make a difference between server and client side actions. PHP is only alvailable on server. HTML, CSS and Javascript is only available on client side. The a tag, with attribute 'href' is only a HTML -also client side only- stuff.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the href tag, without specifying a link, specify your javascript function name.

For example

```
<a href='javascript:myFunction()'> Click Me! <a/>
```

Comment: in ie9 this causes the function to run and navigation away from the page. Never use to do that in ie7. workarounds?

Answer (score 7):

Don't use the `href`, use the `onclick` attribute for this

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="return confirm('are you sure?')">test</a>
```

see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/MtKvN/)

**EDIT**(since code added in question):
this should call your JS function:

```
<?php if($order == 1){ ?>
  <li class="cat-one">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="loadProducts(<?php echo $categoryId ?>)"> 
      <?php echo $categoryName ?> 
    </a>
  </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: And How Can I Write A Function Withen My <Script> Tags

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <html>
    <body>
    <script type= "text/javascript">
    function loadProducts(catid){
        alert(""Hello World!"+catid);
        return false;
    }
    </script>


    <?php if($order == 1){ ?>
    <li class="cat-one">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="loadProducts(<?php echo $categoryId ?>)"><?php echo $categoryName ?> </a>
    </li> 

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your purpose:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="yourFunction();">Link to Click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have jquery library you can call with class:

```
$( ".loadProducts" ).click(function( event ) {
      // Default action of the event will not be triggered.
      event.preventDefault();
      // Get category ID
      var categoryId = $(this).attr('data-categoryid');
      // TODO
      alert("Hello World!");
      return false;
});
```

For:

```
<li class="cat-one"><a href="#" class="loadProducts" data-categoryid="<?php echo $categoryId;?>" > <?php echo $categoryName ?> </a></li>
```